# Dump apache thrift messages for debugging purposes?

Tags: c++, c++17, rpc, thrift, thrift-protocol

[Apache Thrift](https://thrift.apache.org/) is one of the more popular choices for an opensource RPC frameworks (gRPC is also one that gets lot of tracktion since release into the open).

In my setup in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) Im using a [`TMultiplexedProcessor`](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/lib/cpp/src/thrift/processor/TMultiplexedProcessor.h). I guess this could be any `TProcessor` for that matter since Im just interested in printing whatever is sent.

This has a method called:

```
  bool process(std::shared_ptr<protocol::TProtocol> in,
               std::shared_ptr<protocol::TProtocol> out,
               void* connectionContext) override {
```

My idea was to override this again, so that I could print the `in` argument - but how can I write `TProtocol` to output ? (at a glance, it does not seem straightforward to serialize into a string)

I get a feeling there maybe is some other or an easier method. So my question is how can I dump all messages recieved via thrift (for debugging purpose) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's [`TProtocolTap`](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/0140cbf5674c5573d142c95c182f4ba98de99769/lib/cpp/src/thrift/protocol/TProtocolTap.h) and `TDebugProtocol`.

Usage example can be found in [`thrift_dump.cpp`](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/af7ecd6a2b15efe5c6b742cf4a9ccb31bcc1f362/contrib/thrift_dump.cpp):

```
  shared_ptr<TProtocol> iprot(new TBinaryProtocol(itrans));
  shared_ptr<TProtocol> oprot(
      new TDebugProtocol(
        shared_ptr<TTransport>(new TBufferedTransport(
          shared_ptr<TTransport>(new TFDTransport(STDOUT_FILENO))))));

  TProtocolTap tap(iprot, oprot);

 std::string name;
      TMessageType messageType;
      int32_t seqid;
      for (;;) {
        tap.readMessageBegin(name, messageType, seqid);
        tap.skip(T_STRUCT);
        tap.readMessageEnd();
      }
```